# Solving "No handler registered" error for R SHINY

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a SHINY app that uses values of a factor to subset a dataframe and draw a bar plot.

Note that the dataframe has been melted in a previous command set to permit plotting multiple variables on the x-axis. This also seems to prevent R from reading the names of the columns in `temp`.

Upon executing the app, SHINY opens the page yet it quickly closes and throws the following error:

> Warning: Error in : No handler registered for type .clientdata_output__width
>     [No stack trace available]
>   Error in (function (name, val, shinysession)  : 
>     No handler registered for type .clientdata_out...

I can't understand what's wrong with my code.  Can anyone help?

```
# create data
temp<-structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), Workshop = c("Peer Jury Workshop", "Peer Jury Workshop", "School-Based Courts", "School-Based Courts", "School-Based Courts", "School Safety in the 21st Century", "School Safety in the 21st Century"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Engagement", "EncouragedLrg", "Knowledgeable", "LearnNew", "PresenterAgain", "TopicAgain", "Organized", "HandoutsUseful"), class = "factor"),     value = c(1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")


library(shiny);library(plotly);library(tidyverse)
w<-names(temp[ ,c(5)])  # this does not work, why?

  ui <- fluidPage(
      headerPanel("Session Reviewer"),
      sidebarPanel(
          selectInput('Workshop', 'Which workshop?', 
                c("All",unique(as.character(temp$Workshop))))),
      plotOutput(  plotlyOutput('trendPlot', height = "100%")    )  
      )

  server<-function(input,output){
    dataset<-reactive({
      temp
        if(input$Workshop!="All") {dataset<-dataset[dataset$Workshop==input$Workshop,] }  
              })
    output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({

        p<-ggplot(dataset(),aes_string(x=variable,y=value))+geom_bar(stat='summary',fill='cadetblue3')  
        ggplotly(p)
            })  
            }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your question of why `names(temp[ ,c(5)]) ` doesn't work is beacuse everything about it is worng. First you are indexing column 5 and temp only has 4 columns, second what dou you want to do with names? get the rownames?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here with `w<-names(temp[ ,c(5)])`

First, you're trying the select the name of the 5th column of a dataframe that only has 4 columns.

Second, `names(temp)` outputs a list (ie no columns), so sub-setting by column won't work at all.

Something like `names(temp)[4]` will give you the fourth name in your dataframe `temp`, in this case `"values"`.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Furthermore, your handler error is caused by wrapping `plotlyOutput` in `plotOutput`.  Just use `plotlyOutput('trendPlot', height = "100%")` and your app will at least load.  There's still an issue with `x=variable` in your ggplot call, because `variable` isn't defined.